# Asstance with a push menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue with a push menu. I am using the push menu from this site: http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

The issue I am having is with the Main push menu. When you open and then close it, all content is shifted slightly to the left (see screenshot). The Page push menu doe snot have this issue, and when you open the Page menu after the you open and close the Main menu all content is realigned back as it should be. The Page push menu does not have any issues.

Can someone take a look at my HTML and my CSS to see if I am missing something.

You can see the issue here: http://designs.totaleeyou.com/jml-development/header-1/h1-menu-3.html#top

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using? works fine on Chrome OSX.

Comment: It occurs in all the latest browsers for me. It also occurs on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to make changes to the header.article removing the width: 100vw;

```
header.article {
background-attachment: scroll, scroll;
background-clip: border-box, border-box;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 140, 153, 0.6), rgba(0, 140, 153, 0.6)), url("../images/design/lt-campus.jpg");
background-origin: padding-box, padding-box;
background-position: 0 0%, 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat, repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 265px;
width: 100vw; /* Remove this */
}
```

Though the above code fixed the desktop version of this issue, I had to make an additional change for the mobile version of this issue. I had to change the padding from padding:5px; padding:5px 0;

```
#search-container {
background-color: #fdbc5d;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 5px 0; /* CHANGE THIS */
position: absolute;
top: 84px;
width: 100%;
}
```